# The perfect function alias

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17, macros, variadic

For many years, I have waited for function aliases in C++. They still aren't here. I've been using macros to generate wrapper functions. This is my best attempt at the perfect function alias:

```
#define FUN_ALIAS(NEW_NAME, ...)                                                \
  template <typename... Args>                                                   \
  inline decltype(auto) NEW_NAME(Args &&... args)                               \
    noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {              \
    return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                            \
  }
```

I'm using `std::forward` to forward the arguments and I'm using `decltype(auto)` to get the right return type. In the future, we might have `noexcept(auto)` which will be perfect for this situation but I'm not getting my hopes up.

Here's an example from my OpenGL wrapper:

```
template <GLenum TYPE>
Shader<TYPE> makeShader();
template <GLenum TYPE>
Shader<TYPE> makeShader(const GLchar *, size_t);
template <GLenum TYPE, size_t... SIZES>
Shader<TYPE> makeShader(const GLchar (&... sources)[SIZES]);

FUN_ALIAS(makeVertShader, makeShader<GL_VERTEX_SHADER>)
FUN_ALIAS(makeFragShader, makeShader<GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER>)
```

What I want to know:

- Is there a situation where the compiler will not optimize away the wrapper because the wrapper and the original function have different semantics?
- Does this fail to compile for some functions?

Comment: I don't like macros, however this looks really nice! I think this will work unless your alias needs to be a template as well. Why do you need FUN_ALIAS_PTR? Doesn't the other cover it as well?

Comment: @JVApen I actually don't need `FUN_ALIAS_PTR`! I'm trying to think of a reason why it should exist but I've come up short. I think I'll remove it.

Comment: Did you consider wrapper structs? Dumb example typed on mobile: https://ideone.com/iHGUkR

Comment: @DanielJour The problem with it is that it seems to be just storing a function pointer. Your example seems to be equivalent to constexpr auto NEW_NAME = OLD_NAME; It doesn't support overloaded functions. In fact, that's what the discussion about FUN_ALIAS_PTR is about.

Comment: And why not simply `#define makeVertShader makeShader<GL_VERTEX_SHADER>`?

Comment: @bipll namespaces. I have everything in namespace GL {}. For the macro I'd have to do this GL_makeVertShader. I don't like it

Comment: I don't quite follow you. If `makeShader` is defined in ns GL, then you'd call its macro alias as `GL::makeVertShader`, eh? What's the issue with namespaces and macro names?

Comment: You can't put macros in a namespace!

Comment: @Kerndog73 Ah .. you want a way to specify `alias = full_name` and be able to `alias(42)` (for `full_name(42)`) and `alias("answer")` (for `full_name("answer")`) .. basically have overload resolution work on the alias, too. Yes, I guess this is only possible with macros.

Comment: You may find [Boost HOF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/index.html) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking suggestions from the answers, I have written this new and improved function alias macro:

```
#define FUN_ALIAS_SPEC(SPECS, NEW_NAME, ...)                                    \
  template <typename... Args>                                                   \
  SPECS auto NEW_NAME(Args &&... args)                                          \
    noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))                \
    -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {                     \
    return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                            \
  }

#define FUN_ALIAS(NEW_NAME, ...)                                                \
  FUN_ALIAS_SPEC(inline, NEW_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Thanks to **@Justin**, this is now SFINAE friendly by putting the function call expression in `decltype()` rather than using `decltype(auto)`.

Thanks to **@Rakete1111**, this is now `constexpr` friendly by allowing the user to put specifiers before the definition. This means that the alias can also be made into `static` class member.

Thank you both for participating!

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a situation where the compiler will not optimize away the wrapper because the wrapper and the original function have different semantics?

Yes to the first part and no to the second. Any optimizing compiler will inline your wrapper, as it consists of only one return statement.

But on the other hand, the original function might have different semantics: It might be `constexpr` for example, and your alias will not be.

> Does this fail to compile for some functions?

No (except for the `constexpr` part).

So here are some improvements you can use:

1. Templates are implicitly `inline`, so you don't need to write it explicitly.
2. Use a lambda to combat the missing `constexpr`ness of the alias, because since C++17 lambdas are implicitly `constexpr` if they can be.

This will get you:

```
#define FUN_ALIAS(NEW_NAME, ...)                                                \
  inline auto NEW_NAME = [](auto &&... args)                                   \
    noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)))     \
    -> decltype(auto) {                                                        \
    return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);                \
  };
```

Comment: I was using `__VA_ARGS__` so that it wouldn't choke up on template parameter lists like`FUN_ALIAS_WRAP(bar, foo<int, long>)`

Comment: I like the idea of the lambda. Will that automatically be `constexpr` if the call is `constexpr`?

Comment: @Kerndog73 You guessed it :)

Answer (score 4):

This function alias is deficient. `decltype(auto)` will get you the right return type, but [it is not SFINAE friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123393/1896169). For example, the following [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ljmH4e):

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

bool old_name(A i)
{
    return false;
}

FUN_ALIAS(new_name, old_name);

// This does compile if I use old_name instead
template <typename T>
auto something_else(T t)
    -> decltype(new_name(t))
{
    return new_name(t);
}

// If the prior overload SFINAEs away, this overload is chosen
bool something_else(...)
{
    return true;
}

bool foo()
{
    // Tries the first overload (varargs are lowest priority), but
    // it's a hard error instead of SFINAE, because new_name isn't
    // SFINAE friendly
    return something_else(B{});
}
```

Instead of `decltype(auto)`, you need to use a trailing return type:

```
#define FUN_ALIAS(NEW_NAME, ...)                                                \
  template <typename... Args>                                                   \
  inline auto NEW_NAME(Args &&... args)                                         \
    noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))                \
    -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...))                       \
  {                                                                             \
    return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                            \
  }
```

This [allows the prior snippet to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/t8pLTg).

Comment: This is precisely what I was asking for. My exact words were “Does this fail to compile for some functions?” and this is exactly what I meant.